# How to generate block ID for use in post_content JSON data

Tags: block-editor

How does wordpress generate the block ID pointed out in the screen shot below?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elliot Condon of ACF notes that [ACF block ID behavior could be better documented](https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/issues/301#issuecomment-635140075), but here's what I know through my own testing and reading of the documentation:

ACF assigns a new block ID when you first save an ACF block within a post. If you update the block data, such as if you change the block settings, the ID stays the same.

If you create a new post and add an ACF block of the same type, the new block gets a unique block ID.

However, this ACF block ID can be duplicated in some cases, so you can't assume that it's unique across your entire site:
https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/issues/301

The block ID seems to only exist within wp_posts.

When I search wp_posts and wp_postmeta for the block_### ID or even just the ### portion of the ID, the only matching results are from the wp_post entry where the block was saved.

In the [ACF "Blocks" documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/), the "Where is block data saved?" section doesn't specifically explain how ACF block IDs work, but ACF notes that "WordPress saves block data as HTML comments in the post_content. ACF blocks follow suit and save their data as a JSON object within that HTML comment."

If you're looking to retrieve data from your blocks, then in their answer to "Can I load values from other blocks?", ACF recommends that you "load the post_content of a given post, and then parse the blocks using the parse_blocks() function."

Does that help?

Comment: For what I'm doing I've found the php uniqid() function generates these IDs. It looks like ACF may have implemented a JS version of this function acf.uniqid().